# runnng migrations in postgres sql gives error:fatal: morestack on g0

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, migration, database-migration

Im trying to run migration inside my docker container and im getting following error when trying to run migration command

when i run the docker compose up wihtout the migration command

```
/app/migrate -path  /app/migration -database "$DB_SOURCE" -verbose up
```

the app builds fine and my DB SOURCE is

```
DB_SOURCE = "postgresql://root:secret@localhost:5432/simple_bank?sslmode=disable"
```

```
simplebank-api-1       | run db migration 
simplebank-api-1       | fatal: morestack on g0
simplebank-api-1       | SIGTRAP: trace trap
simplebank-api-1       | PC=0x80a8242 m=1 sigcode=128
simplebank-api-1       | 
simplebank-api-1       | goroutine 0 [idle]:
simplebank-api-1       | runtime.abort()
simplebank-api-1       |    runtime/asm_386.s:847 +0x2
simplebank-api-1       | runtime.morestack()
simplebank-api-1       |    runtime/asm_386.s:422 +0x24
simplebank-api-1       | 
simplebank-api-1       | goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
simplebank-api-1       |    goroutine running on other thread; stack unavailable
simplebank-api-1       | 
simplebank-api-1       | eax    0x17
simplebank-api-1       | ebx    0x2
simplebank-api-1       | ecx    0x8fabf6f
simplebank-api-1       | edx    0x17
simplebank-api-1       | edi    0x955cd6f
simplebank-api-1       | esi    0x9c003c0
simplebank-api-1       | ebp    0x98232c0
simplebank-api-1       | esp    0x9c4a630
simplebank-api-1       | eip    0x80a8242
simplebank-api-1       | eflags 0x206
simplebank-api-1       | cs     0x23
simplebank-api-1       | fs     0x0
simplebank-api-1       | gs     0x33
simplebank-api-1 exited with code 2
```

my docker file is following :

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine3.16 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main main.go
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl -L https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/releases/download/v4.15.2/migrate.linux-386.tar.gz   | tar xvz

#run

FROM alpine:3.16

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/main .
COPY --from=builder /app/migrate ./migrate
COPY app.env .
COPY start.sh .
COPY wait.sh .
COPY db/migration ./migration

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/app/main"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/start.sh"]
```

my start.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo "run db migration "

/app/migrate -path  /app/migration -database "$DB_SOURCE" -verbose up


echo "start the app"
exec  "$@"
```

and docker-compose.yaml is following

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=simple_bank
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_SOURCE=postgresql://root:secret@postgres:5432/simple_bank?sslmode=disable
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    entrypoint: ["/app/wait.sh","postgres:5432" , "--", "/app/start.sh"]
    command: ["/app/main"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  migrate.linux-amd64.tar.gz instead of
migrate.linux-386.tar.gz